# How to set circle-color using filters in mapbox data-expression?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Want to show different colored circles on the map using mapbox-gl-js.

Currently it is possible to show different colors using:

```
  'circle-color': [
      "case",
      [">=", ["get", 'count'], 12],
      "#000000",
      "#ffffff"
   ]
```

, but need to perform multiple filter to be performed for single color.

need something like:

```
[">=", ["get", 'count'], 120], && ["<=", ["get", 'count'], 200],
```

and if above results to `true` show red color circle.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `all` expression:

```
   ["all",
      [">=", ["get", 'count'], 120], 
      ["<=", ["get", 'count'], 200],
   ]
```